# com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 400

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, http-status-code-400

I get this 400 error when I compose a tweet using Twitter composer from my android app.

Authetication with Twitter SDK:

```
    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_key), getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_secret)))
            .debug(true)
            .build();
    Twitter.initialize(config);

    twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

    TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

    if (twitterSession == null) {
        twitterAuthClient.authorize(this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession twitterSession = result.data;
                shareOnTwitter(twitterSession);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                showToast("Failed to authenticate user " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else {
        shareOnTwitter(twitterSession);
    }
```

Sharing using TweetComposer :

```
private void shareOnTwitter(TwitterSession twitterSession) {
    Intent intent = new ComposerActivity.Builder(MyShareActivity.this)
                                .session(twitterSession)
                                .image(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
                                .text("Tweet Message")
                                .hashtags("#MyApp")
                                .createIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, SHARE_ON_TWITTER);
}
```

This is the error I get sometimes. It works as expected sometimes.

```
 E/TweetUploadService: Post Tweet failed
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 400
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Could any one help me? Does twitter has any limitation on width or height of the images? I have noticed that it gives this 400 for images with bigger in height. It's failing for image 1080 X 9470. I'm able to tweet the same image using Twitter app and on website too, but not using TweetComposer in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the callback URL in the App that you're using in the twitter developer site to this.

> twittersdk://

Comment: Yes.. I added this callback url. Otherwise it would not work at all. Its working as expected sometimes, and failing sometimes.

Comment: I checked that. It seems relevant but couldn't help me in anyway. This 400 is something related to input request I think.

Comment: Does twitter has any limitation on width or height of the images? I observed that it gives 400 for images with bigger in height. Its failing for image 1080 X 9470 .